# UI Component or Layout?

Tags: magento2, layout, grid, uicomponent

I want to create an admin grid. 
Taking the reference to https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html, I can see there are following two ways :

1. Using Component
2. Using Layout

My question here is which one is better and why?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Each approach has upsides and downsides.
I suggest using the ui-components one because this is where Magento 2 is going right now.
The layouts and blocks approach is just legacy from the M1 version.

But let's take them separately:

Ui Components

- (+) It's mostly configuration. So you write less code, so less code that can break
- (+) you get a cool grid with show/hide columns, full text search, inline edit, export built in and maybe others.
- (+) It can easily be extended with just another xml file in a different module
- (+) any new feature magento rolls out for the grids you will get it automatically in your grid.
- (-) Difficult to debug
- (-) Difficult to build non standard grids
- (-) Not very much control over what happens

Layout files and blocks:

- (+) You got full control of what happens.
- (+) Relatively easy to build non-standard grids.
- (+) Easy to debug
- (+) You can use your knowledge from M1 to do it.
- (-) Grid is not that flexible or extensible.
- (-) you need to write the same code over and over again.
- (-) More code to test or that can break

That's all I have so far. The lists are far from being complete.

Comment: Can we develop specific records export csv functionality via layout grid in M2? Like this: https://prnt.sc/1xdrekr